# VueJS and axios - how to access data in a post request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, this

I have got data like this:

```
  data: () => ({
    input: {
      username: "",
      password: ""
    }
  }),
```

and make a post request like this:

```
loggin_in() {
  if (this.input.username != "" && this.input.password != "") {
    console.log(this.input.username);
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/login", {
        email: this.input.username,
        password: this.input.password
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(this.input.username);
      });
  }
}
```

Logging the first `this.input.username` works, but after that, I have no idea how to access the data. `this` seems to be undefined.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'input' of undefined
```

I dont know why the context of `this` changes here and don´t get how to access my data. Can anybody explain me whats going on and help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the callback you have to bind this or use an arrow function:

```
  .then(function(data) {
         console.log(data);
      })
```

to

```
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(this);
  })
```